# SQL declare datetime - 1001-01-01

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to declare a datetime variable with the value ***1001-01-01 00:00:00.000***

I have tried the following approaches with no luck

```
declare @d1 datetime = '1001-01-01';
declare @d2 datetime = 10010101;
declare @d3 datetime = '1001-01-01 00:00:00';
declare @d4 datetime = cast ('1001-01-01' as datetime)
```

I get the following errors

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Is it possible to declare a `datetime` variable which can hold the value ***1001-01-01 00:00:00.000***?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The minimum valid date for a `DateTime` data type is January 1, 1753.

Try [`DATETIME2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx), using:

```
DECLARE @d4 DATETIME2 = '1001-01-01'
```

The minimum valid date for `DATETIME2` is `0001-01-01`

Comment: `datetime` is not a structure, it's a data type. I think that you have it confused with the `DateTime` structure in the .NET framework. You don't need to cast a date literal to assign it to a `datetime2` variable. Also, was it you who downvoted *all other answers*?

Comment: @Guffa Ah yeah, thanks for the clarity :). Nah it wasn't me, I'll upvote you at the daily reset to thank you for the edit clarifications :).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that. The earliest date that a [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) value can have is 1753-01-01.

Recent versions of Sql Server have the data type [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) that has a larger range:

```
declare @d1 datetime2 = '1001-01-01';
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer and it doesn't warrant a downvote at all. Seems like a drive-by serial downvoter came by

Answer (score 1):

The minimum SQL datetime is January 1,1753, so your date is indeed out-of-range.

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer datetimes must be 1/1/1753 < X < 12/31/9999

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

you will not be able to set a DateTime to that year, so you may want to store it as a string and leave it to the upper layer langague to deal with.